# Child component props not updating after parent's state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I declared a parent component called `EditLinksModal` that uses the `useState` hook. It has a state property `hasError`, which is a JS object whose fields are passed to multiple URLField child components.

However, the child does not seem to be getting the updated props. In fact, it seems that re-rendering isn't happening even though I am calling `setHasError` since any `console.log` statements in the child don't print anything.

I have 3 `console.log` statements below. The 2 `console.log` statements in the parent (`EditLinksModal`) are printing the correct and up-to-date state properties. However, the `console.log` in the child does not even execute. What am I doing wrong ?

Is this because I am using `useState` in combination with a local state property that is a JS Object (ie. `hasError` is an object, but not a really deeply-nested one). Even so, I am puzzled why the `hasError` state property is properly updated, but the child-component doesn't have its `error` prop updated.

```
const URLField = ({label, name, placeholder, value, onHandleChange, error, errorText}) => {
    console.log(error) // problem: not even executing or printing anything
    return (
        <>
            <Header5>{label}</Header5>
            <CustomInput 
                name={name}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                variant="text"
                value={value}
                onChange={(evt) => onHandleChange(name, evt.target.value)} 
            />
            {error && <SystemComponent color={theme.colors.alertAction}>{errorText}</SystemComponent>}
        </>
    )
}

const EditLinksModal = ({visible, handleCloseModal}) => {


    const [hasError, setHasError] = useState({
        facebookUrl: false,
        linkedInUrl: false,
        githubUrl: false,
        websiteUrl: false
    });
    const validateUrl = (errorList, fieldName, fieldValue, allowedHostsList = false) => {
    // .........
    }

    const handleSave = (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();

        const errors = hasError;
        validateUrl(errors, 'facebookUrl', formValues['facebookUrl'], ['facebook.com']);
        validateUrl(errors, 'githubUrl', formValues['githubUrl'], ['github.com']);
        validateUrl(errors, 'linkedInUrl', formValues['linkedInUrl'], ['linkedin.com']);
        validateUrl(errors, 'websiteUrl', formValues['websiteUrl']);
        console.log(errors); // this prints correct, up-to-date values

        setHasError(errors);
    }

    console.log(hasError); // this prints correct, up-to-date values
    return (
        <SystemComponent>
            <URLField
                label="Facebook"
                name="facebookUrl"
                placeholder="Search" 
                value={formValues["facebookUrl"]}
                error={hasError.facebookUrl}
                errorText={"Please Enter Valid Facebook Profile Url."}
                onHandleChange={handleChange}
                />
        </SystemComponent>
    )
```

Comment: Your code seems to be alright. Could it be that `SystemComponent` can block the rendering of `URLField` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the state object `errors` has the same reference, thus `setHasError` does not update the state. If you want to mutate that same object `errors`, then use spread operator to create a new object with the same properties:

```jsx
const handleSave = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const errors = hasError;
    validateUrl(errors, 'facebookUrl', formValues['facebookUrl'], ['facebook.com']);
    validateUrl(errors, 'githubUrl', formValues['githubUrl'], ['github.com']);
    validateUrl(errors, 'linkedInUrl', formValues['linkedInUrl'], ['linkedin.com']);
    validateUrl(errors, 'websiteUrl', formValues['websiteUrl']);
    console.log(errors); // this prints correct, up-to-date values

    // Use spread operator to create a new object
    setHasError({ ...errors });
}
```